# How does accepting or declining changes work on GitHub?

Tags: github

Assume that someone created a project on GitHUb and put there some initial code. Now other users are able to edit/extend the code (maybe not all users but only those who got permissions from the project owner).

What is not clear to me is mechanisms that is used to decide what changes are accepted. Are there voting, meaning that changes are accepted if majority decides so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have upload the code, if someone changes the code and do a Pull Request, you will receive an email, and a notification, to review the changes and you can accept them or decline.

;) It´s easy!

Comment: But if I accept the changes, do they become a part of my own version or there is only one version, that is managed by the project owner? In other words, can it be that case, that I accept changes A and do not accept changes B, but somebody else do not accept changes A and do accept changes B and, as a consequence, I and another user have different versions.

Comment: You can have several branches. And then me for example, I can do a copy (fork) of your repo, then work with it, do some changes, and then, you (owner) or some other people if have permission, can acccept the code. If you accept the code, then will be merged with that branch ;)